# Django-admin, SELECT by fields

Tags: python, django

There is a `UserTask` module in which there are very heavy fields and they break the request, how can I remove them from the query for Django Admin.

They do not appear on the page, but Django uses something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM UserTask;
```

And you need:

```
SELECT id, name, is_user FROM UserTask;
```

It is necessary to remove them in the admin area, here is the registration of the model:

```
class UserTaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('id', 'name')
    list_display = ('id', 'name')    


admin.site.register(UserTask, UserTaskAdmin)
```

original version is [russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/859719/django-admin-select-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC).

Comment: The question is not entirely clear to me. hat is not working?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry, i not not correct translate :(, the request is very long on the page: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/my_app/user_task/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `get_queryset` and use [`only`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only) method:

```
class UserTaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('id', 'name')
    list_display = ('id', 'name') 

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return UserTask.objects.only('id', 'name')
```

Comment: Thank you, can be use `self.model` for place `UserTask`?

Comment: @users you are welcome! Yep, `return self.model.objects.only('id', 'name')` looks better, thanks!:)